# Unable to run https git clone using go-git and access token

Tags: git, go, go-git

Using `go-git/v5` and trying to clone over `https` as follows:

```
    _, err := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), fs, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL:           repo,
        ReferenceName: plumbing.ReferenceName(branch),
        Depth:         1,
        SingleBranch:  true,
        Auth:          &http.TokenAuth{Token: string(token)},
    })
```

where `token` is a string of the form `ghp_XXXXXXXXX` (my personal GH access token)

and `repo` equals to my private repo `https://github.com/pkaramol/arepo`

The error is

```
"net/http: invalid header field value \"Bearer ghp_XXXXXXXXX`\\n\" for key Authorization"
```

I have also trying using basic auth with my username and the token as password

```
    _, err := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), fs, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL:           repo,
        ReferenceName: plumbing.ReferenceName(branch),
        Depth:         1,
        SingleBranch:  true,
        Auth:          &http.BasicAuth{Username: "pkaramol", Password: token},
    })
```

Now the error becomes:

```
authentication required
```

What is the proper way of cloning over https?

The token has `repo` scope fwiw

edit:

the `fs` is instantiated as follows

```
fs := memfs.New()
```

the `http` package used is the following

```
"github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/transport/http"
```

Comment: Your `BasicAuth` example works fine for me. Can you edit your post with the exact imports you're using the and surrounding code (`fs` instantiation for example)?

Comment: added some updates, let me know if it is not enough

Comment: Yeah we're aligned, it works for me. Something's wrong with your token would be my guess. I assume you tried creating a new token. How do instantiate the token? I simply do `token := "ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

Comment: I'll post my code as an answer so you can compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-git/go-billy/v5/memfs"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/transport/http"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/storage/memory"

    git "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"
)

func main() {
    token := "ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    fs := memfs.New()

    _, err := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), fs, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL:           "https://github.com/username/reponame",
        ReferenceName: plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/heads/main"),
        Depth:         1,
        SingleBranch:  true,
        Auth:          &http.BasicAuth{Username: "username", Password: token},
        Progress:      os.Stdout,
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Comment: duh....there was a `\n` char in my token variable (I am reading it from a file). thanks for getting into the trouble of answering it, I am accepting your answer